# In pillow library, BICUBIC is not working

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, bicubic

This is my code.

```
import sys, os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from scipy import *
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/research')

im = Image.open('C:/research/1.jpg')
hei, wei = im.height, im.width

im_bicubic = im.resize((wei,hei), im.BICUBIC)

im.save('C:/research/1ori.jpg')            #original image
im_bicubic.save('C:/research/1bic.jpg')    #Images with bicubic applied
```

But I get this error.

```
AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'BICUBIC'
```

Why is this message coming up?

`.bmp`, the same message pops up.

What should I do?

Comment: have you tried my solution ? did it help ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `PIL.Image.BICUBIC` instead of `im.BICUBIC`.

So you need to change:

```
im_bicubic = im.resize((wei,hei), im.BICUBIC)
```

to

```
im.resize((wei,hei),PIL.Image.BICUBIC)
```

You also need to import pil like so:

```
import PIL
```

Comment: Since a `from PIL import Image` has already been done, a plain `Image.BICUBIC` could be used instead of `PIL.Image.BICUBIC` and then there woujd be no need to add an `import PIL`.

Comment: @martineau `Image.BICUBIC` evaluates to `3`, so one could so use that constant

Comment: Sure, but using a magic number like that (and not the official name assigned to the value) completely defeats whole purpose of having them in the first place and is generally considered a poor programming practice.

Comment: @martineau totally agree

Comment: @ONION feel free to accept the answer, if it has helped